# User Defined Array formulas in DataNitro

Tags: datanitro

I have created a python function to exponentiate a matrix and imported it as a user defined function in Excel using DataNitro. However, when I use this formula I get  the result as a python list in one cell.

Is it possible to create array formulas for excel using DataNitro similar in lines to MMULT or MINVERSE?

Below is my python code and a snapshot of the excel sheet:

> functions.py

```
import numpy as np

def mat_expo(x,n):
    if(n==2):
        return mat_mult(x,x)
    else:
        return mat_mult(x,mat_expo(x,n-1))

def mat_mult(x,y):
    return np.dot(x,y)
```

> Excel Sheet:

[my excel sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oL0nW.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to return to multiple cells from one DataNitro function. You can get the same result as follows:

```
def mat_expo_entry(x, n, i, j):
    return mat_expo(x, n)[i][j]
```

Use `=mat_expo_entry($B$2:$D$4,3,ROW()-7,COLUMN()-2)` in your sample spreadsheet in cells `B7:D9` to print the output correctly.

If this is slow, you can store the answer using Python's built-in lru cache:

```
from functools32 import lru_cache # use 'functools' in Python3

@lru_cache
def mat_expo(x,n):
if(n==2):
    return mat_mult(x,x)
else:
    return mat_mult(x,mat_expo(x,n-1))
```

Alternatively, you could use a DataNitro script to print the result directly to the sheet.